# GEdit High CPU usage C programming

Tags: 14.10, gedit

I am newbie on the ubuntu and C programming. One they I said I should try ubuntu and here I am. I heard a lot that GEdit is a great tool for programming.I tried that It is absolutely normal when I am writing on "plain text" but as soon as I changed into "C" It nearly uses %100 of my CPU. Is it some kind of bug that I am dealing here or Shouldn I simply don't use Gedit for C at all. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Have you installed any plug-ins for Gedit ? I'd suggest you switch to Geany, which should work smoothly. Personally, I've been using just command line text editors, like vi or nano, and compiling with gcc command. Never fails and always smooth :)

Comment: I installed but , as I read some online articles I disabled them all because they said plugins can cause that. But still have the same problem. And I tried Geany just now and works perfectly :3